# Can I move about the axes in a matplotilb subplot?

Tags: matplotlib, axes, subplot

Once I have created a system of subplots in a figure with

```
        fig, ((ax1, ax2)) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
```

can I play around with the position of `ax2`, for example, by shifting it a little bit to the right or the left?

In other words, can I customize the position of an axes object in a figure after it has been created as a subplot element?
If so, how could I code this?

Thanks for thinking along

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use commands `get_position` and `set_position` like in this example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ((ax1, ax2)) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
box = ax1.get_position()
box.x0 = box.x0 + 0.05
box.x1 = box.x1 + 0.05
ax1.set_position(box)
plt.show()
```

which results in this:

[image: Shifting matplotlib subplot]

You'll notice I've used attributes `x0` and `x1` (first and last X coordinate of the box) to shift the plot in `0.05` in that axis. The logic applies to y also.

In fact should the shift be to big and the boxes will overlap (like in this image with a shift of `0.2`).

[image: big shift with overlapping plots in matplotlib]

Comment: Is there an equivalent for fig = plt.figure() instead of fig, ax = plt.subplots()?