# Overlap polar plots to create a radial tornado chart in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to recreate this:
[image]

And I have most of it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd



color_dict = {"Denmark": "#A54836", "Norway": "#2B314D", "Sweden": "#5375D4"}
data = {
    "year": [2004, 2022, 2004, 2022, 2004, 2022],
    "countries" : ["Sweden", "Sweden", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Norway", "Norway"],
    "sites": [13,15,4,10,5,8]
}

df= pd.DataFrame(data)

df['sub_total'] = df.groupby('year')['sites'].transform('sum')
df = df.sort_values(['countries', 'sites'], ascending=True ).reset_index(drop=True)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10,5), facecolor = "#FFFFFF", subplot_kw=dict(polar=True) )
fig.tight_layout(h_pad=-40)

countries = df.countries.unique()
colors = color_dict.keys()
years = df.year.unique()

offsets=[0.3,0.2,0.15]
directions = [1,-1]
ylabel = [0.58, 0.68, 0.78]
for ax,year, direction in zip(axes.ravel(),years, directions):
    temp_df = df[df.year==year]
    for  i, (country,site, color,offset,yl) in enumerate(zip(temp_df.countries, temp_df.sites, colors, offsets, ylabel)):
        angle_range = np.linspace(0, site*7)
        theta =[np.deg2rad(a) for a in angle_range]
        r = np.full(len(angle_range), i + 1)  # identical radius values to draw an arc
        print(theta,r)
        ax.plot(theta,
            r,
            linewidth=15,
            solid_capstyle="round",
            color=color_dict[color])
        ax.text(0.49,yl, country,transform=plt.gcf().transFigure, ha = "center")
        ax.annotate(site, xy= ( theta[-1],r[-1]), color="w",ha="center" ,va="center")
    # increase the r limit, making a bit more space to show thick arcs correctly
    ax.set_rmax(4)
    ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
    ax.set_theta_direction(direction)
    ax.grid(False)
    #ax.set_thetamax(180)

    ax.axis('off')
```

Which produces this:
[image]

and with the axes on:
[image]

My question is:

Is there a way to overlap the axes so i get them closer together?

I can not do #ax.set_thetamax(180) because it will cut the rounded edges at the beginning:
[image]

I have also tried tight_layout which has worked with cartesian axes, but not with polar and
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0) does nothing

Bonus question:
How can I position the radial labels and the data labels (country names, respectively) without hardcoding the offset?

Comment: Please focus on one question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak the distance subplot separation as follows (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241029/can-i-move-about-the-axes-in-a-matplotilb-subplot)):

```py
    ...

    shift_axes = 0.18 if direction == 1 else -0.21

    box = ax.get_position()
    box.x0 = box.x0 + shift_axes
    box.x1 = box.x1 + shift_axes
    ax.set_position(box)
```